# How can I built this self-paced learning loss function and use it in keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function, data-generation

I'm trying to implemment self-paced learning (SPL) in my keras model. I was focused on [this work](https://towardsdatascience.com/self-paced-learning-for-machine-learning-f1c489316c61), where self-paced learning is also applied to a deep learning model but the implemmentation is done using pytorch. I'm having some trouble converting the following pythoch code to keras.

**Creating loss function**

```
import torch
from torch import Tensor
import torch.nn as nn


class SPLLoss(nn.NLLLoss):
    def __init__(self, *args, n_samples=0, **kwargs):
        super(SPLLoss, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.threshold = 0.1
        self.growing_factor = 1.3
        self.v = torch.zeros(n_samples).int()

    def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor, index: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        super_loss = nn.functional.nll_loss(input, target, reduction="none")
        v = self.spl_loss(super_loss)
        self.v[index] = v
        return (super_loss * v).mean()

    def increase_threshold(self):
        self.threshold *= self.growing_factor

    def spl_loss(self, super_loss):
        v = super_loss < self.threshold
        return v.int()
```

**Applying loss function to train**

```
import torch.optim as optim

from model import Model
from dataset import get_dataloader
from loss import SPLLoss


def train():
    model = Model(2, 2, 2, 0)
    dataloader = get_dataloader()
    criterion = SPLLoss(n_samples=len(dataloader.dataset))
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

    for epoch in range(10):
        for index, data, target in dataloader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(data)
            loss = criterion(output, target, index)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        criterion.increase_threshold()
    return model
```

**1.** How can I define my loss function(SPL_loss) accordingly?
**2.** How can I use model.fit() and increase the threshold between trains in keras since I'm using [this data generator](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) to load the data?